# como adicionar a una variable de estado un array recibido del endpoint con react

Tags: reactjs

Estoy recibiendo de un endpoint un array de que debo introducir en una variable de estado de mi proyecto, el array es el siguiente:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Elemento 1'
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Elemento 2'
 }]
```

y mi variable de estado es la siguiente: `const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);`

cuando recibo de mi endpoint este array lo estoy adicionando a mi variable de estado de la siguiente manera:

```
const new_elements = [];
 new_elements = resp.data;

new_elements .map((item) => {
            setElements([item, ...elements]);
          })
```

Pero me esta sucediendo que solo me adiciona dentro de la variable de estado un solo elemento. Que puede estar sucediendo

Comment: Puede tener relación con el primer render, cuando dices `adicionando a mi variable de estado de la siguiente manera` ¿Como lo adicionas? agrega esa pieza de código, poque esto `new_elements = resp.data` parece buggy, se esperaria que usaras `useEffect` o un `customHook`para agregar los datos al estado

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás actualizando el estado dentro del método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) de la lista que recibes en la respuesta.

La actualización del estado no se hace inmediatamente, se hace de forma asíncrona, y el mismo estará totalmente actualizado cuando React vuelva a hacer render del componente. Hasta ese momento, el estado que lees en cada iteración es el mismo estado antes de empezar a recorrer tu Array de resultados.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente snippet, puedes ver que en cada iteración se intenta actualizar el estado, pero al usar `console.log` para ver el estado después de actualizarlo, vemos que el mismo aún no se actualiza, ni siquiera en la siguiente iteración. El mismo se actualizará cuando el componente se renderice, y esto no ocurrirá hasta que el método que llamó a `map` finalice.

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<!-- Don't use this in production: -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    const articles = [
      { id: 1, name: "Television" },
      { id: 2, name: "Fridge" },
      { id: 3, name: "Kitchen" },
    ];

    const response = {
      data: [
        { id: 4, name: "Playstation" },
        { id: 5, name: "Air Conditioner" },
      ]
    }
    
    function List() {
    
      const [ arrState, setArrState ] = React.useState(articles)
      function handleClick(event) {
        event.target.disabled = true
        response.data.map(element => {
          setArrState(prev => ([element, ...prev]))
          console.log(arrState)
        })
      }
     
      return (
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Añadir</button>
      )
    }
    const container = document.getElementById('root')
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container)
    root.render(<List />)
</script>
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es NO ACTUALIZAR el estado dentro de `map`.

Si los elementos de tu respuesta son o tienen datos que no necesitas modificar, entonces podrías usar la [sintaxis `spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) directamente dentro del método que recibe el estado previo y devuelve el nuevo estado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// resp.data contiene los elementos nuevos que deseas añadir a tu lista
setElements(prevElements => ([...prevElements, ...resp.data]))
```

Pero si necesitaras modificar o pre procesar los datos recibidos, en ese caso podrías usar `map` sobre `resp.data` pero sin intentar alterar el estado dentro de `map` sino al finalizar, con el resultado obtenido.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// primero obtengo los elementos con los datos que necesito
const newElements = resp.data.map(element => ({ id: element.id, name: element.name}))
// ahora puedo actualizar el estado
setElements(prevElements => ([...prevElements, ...newElements]))
```

Te dejo un código funcional para que puedas ver cómo se actualiza correctamente la lista de elementos utilizando la sintaxis `spread`.

**Nota**

No hagas caso de la advertencia que aparece en la consola de resultado, tiene que ver con el entorno sandboxed de Stack Overflow y la forma en que renderiza los elementos con Babel y React.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<!-- Don't use this in production: -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    const articles = [
      { id: 1, name: "Television" },
      { id: 2, name: "Fridge" },
      { id: 3, name: "Kitchen" },
    ];

    const response = {
      data: [
        { id: 4, name: "Playstation" },
        { id: 5, name: "Air Conditioner" },
      ]
    }

    function List() {  
      const [ arrState, setArrState ] = React.useState(articles);
    
      function handleClick(event) {
        event.target.disabled = true
        setArrState(prevState => ([...prevState, ...response.data]))
      }
    
      const items = arrState.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)
    
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>{items}</ul>
          <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Añadir</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  
    const container = document.getElementById('root')
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container)
    root.render(<List />)

</script>
```